# Why are these presence validations failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to validate a model using :presence => true on certain fields, but the model is being returned as valid even if these fields are nil. Here are the validations of my Replay model:

```
validate :match_id, :presence => true
validate :replay_url, :presence => true
validate :uploader_id, :presence => true
```

If I open up the console and type the following, you can see what I mean:

```
1.9.3p0 :001 > r = Replay.new
 => #<Replay id: nil, match_id: nil, replay_url: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, uploader_id: nil> 
1.9.3p0 :002 > r.valid?
 => true
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: The symbol you give to `validate` is called and it is expected to add errors via `errors.add` to indicate that something is wrong, the return value is ignored. You will have a `match_id` method through AR so `validate :match_id` will run even though it won't work as you expect. The answers have it right but I figured out might like to know why your incorrect code failed silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use method [validates](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) instead of [validate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate).

Answer (score 1):

validate**s**

```
validates :match_id, :presence => true
validates :replay_url, :presence => true
validates :uploader_id, :presence => true
```